web_view flutter notworking
I am going to use webview_flutter in my flutter app but it is not working and showing this
Exception
_AssertionError ('package:webview_flutter_platform_interface/src/platform_webview_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 26 pos 7: 'WebViewPlatform.instance != null': A platform implementation for webview_flutter has not been set.Please ensure that an implementation of WebViewPlatform has been set to WebViewPlatform.instance before use. For unit testing, WebViewPlatform.instance can be set with your own test implementation.)
I changed minSDK version 19 but still not working.

can you share the code.
